# How to declare a public Form after Main() in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to declare a form instance before `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` (found in Main()) I get the exception:

---

System.InvalidOperationException: 'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.'

---

How do I declare a public form after the Main() function?

edit: I want to have access to my instance of the form in another function

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write  `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` before `InitializeComponent();` in your Form.cs.